# SAAS framework for Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, saas

I want to know about good SAAS (Software as a Service) Framework for application development using Java. I have seen there are solutions for Domain(DB) model. But i like to know about a framework or frameworks which can be use for business logic as well. For example same business login and domain objects to support multi-tenancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My 2 cents.

When people are talking about SaaS essentially it includes the following aspects.

- A service discovery and registration layer which takes care of service registry and discovery.
- A messaging layer which could route the message to relevant counterparties with or without knowing the physical address.
- A uniform data transform format so all services could understand it regardless which language they are written in.
- A threading / process model which enables the caller of the services to run across thread/process boundary.

The close match of the above is Spring Framework; but I am a light user of such frameworks because it introduces 20% of the function you need with 80% of the useless stuff which pollute your workspace seriously. IMHO I think

1. If you are after some general performance, try the combination of Spring + JMS + protobuf + JDK threading lib.
2. If you are after some high performance, you need to implement the above features yourself. E.g. your discovery/registry model + Tibco RV + your messaging object pool or KYRO + your threading lib upon JDK lib.

Hope that helps.